# Find files belonging to a user with size in MB on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: command-line, find

I am using this command which is working fine:

```
sudo find / -user web132 -ls
```

But when I am trying like

```
sudo find / -user web132 -ls -lh
```

I am getting a wrong syntax error. How can I get the file sizes belonging to a user in MB?

Comment: you get syntax error probably because -ls is a flag to find command, not separate instance of ls, so it cannot take -lh flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `exec` predicate of `find`:

```
sudo find / -user web132 -exec ls -lh {} +
```

This will execute `ls -lh` under the `-exec` predicate of `find` and will give you output in the human readable format. If you want to output always in megabytes you need some additional operations, the `-h` option in your `ls -lh` suggesting that you only want the output in human readable format.

Comment: As an aside, you can actually have `find` run any command on the files it finds.

Comment: @heemayl find has -ls flag, which displays files in the ls format

Comment: @Serg The answer to your statement is in the question itself  :)

Comment: @heemayl I've comented on that already, check it

Comment: @Serg the question is to show the output os `ls` in a human readable format..i don't know what you are getting at..

Comment: @heemayl I do apologize, I thought OP merely wanted to know how why the -lh flags didn't work. I didn't realize he actually wants to simulate `ls -lh` command with find

Comment: @Serg come on..why apologizing..

Comment: @heemayl well, I can be a little annoying at times. Anyway, can you please review my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -size +100k -size -500M -user web132
```

This means to find a file larger than 100kb and smaller than 500mb.  The `-ls` option is about how the output is formatted, and has little to do with the `ls` command.

Comment: Uppercase K in +100K didn't work for me,but lowercase works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's find + awk + numfmt version. Because -ls is a flag to find command, not an instance of ls, you cannot use -lh flags as well. However, if you insist on using the `-ls` flag with find, we can also try format the file size into human readable form. File size in output of `find` with -ls flag is field #7, thus using [awk's two-way io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960911/3701431), we just convert that field to a human readable form, and substitute it back.

```
find / -user web132 -ls | 
 awk '{ command="numfmt --to=iec "; command $7 | getline result; $7=result;print; close(command) }'
```

Here's example with my home folder:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -user xieerqi -ls | awk '{ command="numfmt --to=iec "; command $7 |& getline result; $7=result;print; close(command) }'   
3018363 4 drwxr-xr-x 43 xieerqi xieerqi 4.0K Jun 22 00:33 .
3409153 4 drwx------ 3 xieerqi xieerqi 4.0K Jun 22 00:33 ./.gconf
3018459 4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 756 Jun 11 00:08 ./record
3018368 16 -rw------- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 13K Jun 21 23:14 ./.bash_history
3018364 12 -rw-r--r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 8.8K May 28 03:59 ./examples.desktop
3018535 4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 64 Jun 21 16:04 ./testfile.txt
3018473 4 drwxrwxr-x 2 xieerqi xieerqi 64 Jun 16 23:28 ./netmanager
```

**Note:** from the discussion in the comments bellow, it seems that `mawk` has issues, but `gawk`(GNU awk) works perfectly fine. I've figured out an approach for mawk, which merely makes use of replacing $7 not as an argument, but as part of the command, that later gets expanded. Here's what I mean:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -user xieerqi -ls | mawk '{command="numfmt --to=iec "$7; command  | getline var; $7=var;print  }'`

Comment: You probably should `close` the `numfmt` command: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html

Comment: @muru addressed that already. Thank you for the info, didn't know that

Comment: i am getting `unexpected character '&'`

Comment: @heemayl how about removing & from |& ? does that have an effect ? Do you use gnu awk  or something else, like mawk ? run `awk --version` command.

Comment: i am using `mawk`

Comment: @heemayl have you tried it with | not with |& ?

Comment: @muru what's your awk ? does it have same error as heemayl's ?

Comment: it is interpreting the file sizes without `&`.....`/bin/sh: 1: 4096: not found`

Comment: I used `gawk`, so no problems here.

Comment: @heemayl yup, I reproduced that same error with mawk. With GNU awk - no problems

Comment: @heemayl got it working with mawk. Please check the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can print the sizes of files in bytes using the `find` alone with `%s` format specifier:

```
find / -user web132 -printf "%p %s\n"
```

Since you want the size in megabytes, let's divide the last field by 1024*1024 using `awk`:

```
find / -user web132 -printf "%p %s\n" |  awk '{printf "%sB %fMB\n", $0, $NF/1048576.0}'
```

This way you'll always have the output in megabytes, unlike with `ls -lh` option that will use smaller units for smaller files.

There is also `%k` specifier that will use 1K block, so alternatively you can use:

```
find / -user web132 -printf "%p %k\n" |  awk '{printf "%sB %fMB\n", $0, $NF/1024.0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** `find … -ls …` is not the same as `ls`. If you need some parameters for `ls` you need the command `ls`. And `-lh` isn't a parameter for `find`, therefore the error.

---

`find … -exec …` is a good option. You could use also:

```
sudo find / -user web132 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh {}
```